# issue of derived class pointer casted to base class pointer and cast back

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

I am confused by a design that I saw recently. It initialize a derived class object in the main function and pass it as a base class object into a function. Then, inside the function that object pointer is casted back to the derived class again. Is this a design pattern or should it be avoid?

Also, a member variable exclusive to the derived class is used after the pointer being converted to the base class and back to the derived class again. How would the pointer easily find the variable after the process?

```
class Base
{
    // something
}

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void funcDerived() {return x;}
    int x = 0;
}

int process(std::shared_ptr<Base> const& var)
{
    auto new_var = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(var);
    return new_var->funcDerived();
}

int main()
{
    auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>(new Derived());
    derived->x = 5;
    process(derived);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
To add some details of this design, the base class is an abstract class while there are several derived classes for different version. Function `process()` is an API whose interface remains intact. Its behavior is controlled by conditional-compilation directives.

Comment: Not ideal, but could be a solution in some cases. Depends on the context. You you have more details? Edit: you should probably check the return of the dynamic cast, to see if it worked.

Comment: Does `Base` have any virtual functions?

Comment: `process()` doesn't check if the cast was successful before de-referencing. I'd say that's malformed and a bad time waiting to happen. This is before we get into the whole shared vs. unique thing.

Comment: The way it is over here I don't see why it should be useful. I mean at least add `process` as a `static` member function: One could pass another `shared_ptr` which inherits from `Base` but is not of type `Derived` and then the `new_var` will be a `nullptr`. The function seems somehow superfluous...

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes the Base class is an abstract class

Comment: @JHBonarius it works, and I am curious why it works

Comment: No it doesn't fully work. Like said, the dynamic cast is not checked. The input to process doesn't point to a Derivative object (e.g. null, Base or other derivative of Base), it will fail. And talking about "curious", this could be part of a curiously recurring template pattern CRTP.

Comment: 1. If you see a downcast, you see a faulty design (p < 0.05). 2. A pointer doesn't need to "find" anything. An object of type `Derived` looks exactly like any other object of type `Derived`, regardless of where a pointer that points to it comes from. That's a fundamental property of C++ objects. So as long as we have a pointer that points to `Derived`, we are good.